# objdump -- File Truncated

Tags: c, assembly, executable, disassembly, objdump

When I run `objdump -d <program name>` on a linux server (at University) I get the following:

```
kmwe236@kmwe236:~/Downloads/buflab-handout$ objdump -d bufbomb
objdump: bufbomb: File truncated
```

What's going on here?

Comment: How was `bufbomb` created?

Comment: Likely your file doesn't conform to the known object file specifications known by your version of objdump. Is it possible the file in question is a raw binary? If so you could use ndisasm if available to dump the binary (if you needed a disassembly)

Answer (score 2):

I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04.

I entered, on the command line,

```
objdump -d untitled
```

where 'untitled' is an executable file

It ran successfully with out any 'file truncated' message.

I entered, on the command line,

```
objdump -d untitled.o
```

where 'untitled.o' is an object file

It ran successfully with out any 'file truncated' message.

Therefore, I strongly suspect the 'bufbomb' file is not a valid executable or object file.

Comment: hmm, hard to disagree with that... I'm able to disassemble locally using `gobjdump` as a part of the `binutils` package. But on my linux server I still can't get it to work. Weird.